# How many times have two teams from the same continent contested the World Cup Final?

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup

There is a chance that Germany and the Netherlands will play in the 2014 World Cup Final, so here is a related question. How many times have two teams from the same continent contested the World Cup Final? Please provide the year of the tournament and the countries playing the final, as well as the eventual winner.

Comment: Wikipedia: [List of FIFA World Cup finals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_finals)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me list out the FIFA world cup finals in which two countries from same continent faced each other.

```
2018:       FRANCE vs CROATIA        4-2
2010:        SPAIN vs NETHERLANDS    1–0
2006:        ITALY vs FRANCE         1–1 (5–3p)
1982:        ITALY vs WEST GERMANY   3-1
1974: WEST GERMANY vs NETHERLANDS    2–1
1966:      ENGLAND vs WEST GERMANY   4–2
1954: WEST GERMANY vs HUNGARY        3–2
1950:      URUGUAY vs BRAZIL         2-1 (final match in a round-robin)
1938:        ITALY vs HUNGARY        4–2
1934:        ITALY vs CZECHOSLOVAKIA 2–1
1930:      URUGUAY vs ARGENTINA      4–2
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it's easier to count the finals played between countries NOT from the same continent.

```
1958:       Brazil vs Sweden         5-2
1962:       Brazil vs Czechoslovakia 3-1
1970:       Brazil vs Italy          4-1
1978:    Argentina vs Netherlands    3-1
1986:    Argentina vs West Germany   3-2
1990: West Germany vs Argentina      1-0    
1994:       Brazil vs Italy          0-0 (3-2)    
1998:       France vs Brazil         3-0    
2002:       Brazil vs Germany        2-0
2014:      Germany vs Argentina      1-0
```

There were 21 World Cup finals: 10 were intercontinental, 11 were from the same continent.

Cute fact: When it's different continent match, somehow it's either Argentina or Brazil ;=)

Comment: actually almost everytime Argentina or Brazil wins! in 1998 France beat Brazil to win the cup.

Comment: Argentina won. A sign?

Comment: Missing 1990: Germany v Argentina 1-0 (Argentina the first team not to score in a World Cup Final). Pedantic point: 1986 was West Germany.

Comment: *"Cute fact: When it's different continent match, somehow it's either Argentina or Brazil"* - Well, as cute as the fact is, it isn't so unlikely, seeing that those are the best South American teams and to be honest, North America, Africa and Asia are pretty much out of discussion. Though, I would have guessed Uruguay to show up, at least in the earlier cups, but then it was probably a South America only match.